# Using Read Replicas with Redis

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, redis

Does Magento Enterprise have any means of using read replicas when using Redis as a back-end cache? If not, any tips on how this could be added?

Magento uses `Credis_Client` by Colin Mollenhour, who also offers a `Client_Cluster` class: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/credis/tree/74b2b703da5c58dc07fb97e8954bc63280b469bf However, I don't see this included in Magento by default.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no configuration in Magento needed as the replication is set up on (redis) application level.

From what I've seen in the documentation [here](http://redis.io/topics/replication), it's enough to set this up in the redis configruation.

Comment: I am using ElastiCache with read replication setup, and even though Magento is pointing at the replication group's endpoint, Magento only ever reads from the primary (aka "master") node. I want to set it up to read from multiple nodes, and write to one.

Comment: I see. Hope to find someone experienced with that to answer here.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that I eventually came up with.

1) I updated `/lib/Credis/Client.php` and added `/lib/Credis/Cluster.php` using the latest versions from Colin Mollenhour.

2) I replaced the single Redis cluster connection line in `/lib/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php` with a Cluster connection.

Original:

```
$this->_redis = new Credis_Client($options['server'], $options['port'], $timeout, $persistent);
```

New:

```
$cluster = false;
if (class_exists('Credis_Cluster') && array_key_exists('cluster', $options) && !empty($options['cluster'])) {
    $clusterNodes = array();

    if (array_key_exists('master', $options['cluster']) && !empty($options['cluster']['master'])) {
        foreach ($options['cluster']['master'] as $masterNode) {
            if (empty($masterNode['server']) || empty($masterNode['port'])) {
                continue;
            }

            $clusterNodes[] = array(
                'host'       => $masterNode['server'],
                'port'       => $masterNode['port'],
                'alias'      => 'master',
                'master'     => true,
                'write_only' => true,
                'timeout'    => $timeout,
                'persistent' => $persistent,
                'db'         => (int)$options['database'],
                'password'   => $options['password'],
            );
            break; // limit to 1
        }
    }

    if (!empty($clusterNodes) && array_key_exists('slave', $options['cluster']) && !empty($options['cluster']['slave'])) {
        foreach ($options['cluster']['slave'] as $slaveNodes) {
            if (empty($masterNode['server']) || empty($masterNode['port'])) {
                continue;
            }

            $clusterNodes[] = array(
                'host'       => $slaveNodes['server'],
                'port'       => $slaveNodes['port'],
                'alias'      => 'slave' . count($clusterNodes),
                'timeout'    => $timeout,
                'persistent' => $persistent,
                'db'         => (int)$options['database'],
                'password'   => $options['password'],
            );
        }
    }

    if (!empty($clusterNodes)) {
        $cluster = true;
        $this->_redis = new Credis_Cluster($clusterNodes);
    }
}

if (!$cluster || !$this->_redis) {
    $this->_redis = new Credis_Client($options['server'], $options['port'], $timeout, $persistent);
}
```

3) I updated `/app/etc/local.xml` to include a new `<cluster>` tag inside `<global><cache><backend_options>` and `<global><full_page_cache><backend_options>` like the following:

```
<cluster>
    <master>
        <node-001>
            <server>elasticache-replicationgroup-endpoint-here</server>
            <port>6379</port>
        </node-001>
    </master>
    <slave>
        <node-001>
            <server>elasticache-cluster-001-endpoint-here</server>
            <port>6379</port>
        </node-001>
        <node-002>
            <server>elasticache-cluster-002-endpoint-here</server>
            <port>6379</port>
        </node-002>
    </slave>
</cluster>
```

4) To test, I temporarily modified the `connect()` method in `/lib/Credis/Client.php` to add the following right before the `return` statement:

```
Mage::log('Connected to '.$this->getHost(), null, 'redis.log', true);
```

With these changes, I can see that the ElastiCache Replication Group endpoint is being connected to for *writes*, and the other ElastiCache Cluster endpoints are being connected to at random for *reads*. This has introduced true read replica support to Redis in Magento, and has significantly improved performance and stability during high load.